# Having trouble connecting to azure sql database

Tags: azure-sql-database, windows-server-2012-r2

We have an Azure Web Sql Web database

Which we are trying to connect to a asp.net app on another vps runnning microsoft server 2012.
I have added the relevant ip to azure SQL allowed ip's and I have opened tcp 1433 inbound and outbound on the VPS .

The connection string format in config which succesfully works on localhost while running a local db is

```
    <connectionStrings>
<add name="db_connection" connectionString="Data Source=my server name;  Initial Catalog=bidstreet;  user=mydbuser;  password=mypassword;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

even on localhost (locahost ip also added to azure allowed ip's list)  when I try to use  the azure details it reurns

> ```
> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"}
> ```

I have tried using the ado connection string from Azure console which just throughs a hissy fit.

but in studio web or SQL Server Management studio I can connect and test using the same settings.

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify that Data Source has format `tcp:< server name >`?